# How can I add items to a UITableView in a specific order?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making an App that has a list of items in a UITableView that gets its data from an array. The items are loaded into the list just fine, however they are not ordered in the way I have them in my loadAnnotations method (read on).

Below is the code for loading my annotations (which is what I am displaying in my list), as well as the code for setting the text of my cells in my UITable to the names of the annotations.

Everything gets loaded into my list fine, but the ordering is random.  Any ideas?

```
-(void) loadOutAnnotations
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

    //***********HOTELS**************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 40.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -73.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel1 setTitle:@"Hotel 1"];
    [hotel1 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #1"];
    [hotel1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel1];


    workingCoordinate.latitude = 50.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -83.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel2 setTitle:@"Hotel 2"];
    [hotel2 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #2"];
    [hotel2 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 60.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -93.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel3 setTitle:@"Hotel 3"];
    [hotel3 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #3"];
    [hotel3 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 10.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -23.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel4 setTitle:@"Hotel 4"];
    [hotel4 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #4"];
    [hotel4 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 30.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -43.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *hotel5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [hotel5 setTitle:@"Hotel 5"];
    [hotel5 setSubtitle:@"This is Hotel #5"];
    [hotel5 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels];

    [mapView addAnnotation:hotel5];

    // *****************AERIALS*****************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 25.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -15.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [aerial1 setTitle:@"Aerial 1"];
    [aerial1 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #1"];
    [aerial1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial1];


    workingCoordinate.latitude = 35.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -25.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [aerial2 setTitle:@"Aerial 2"];
    [aerial2 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #2"];
    [aerial2 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 45.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -35.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [aerial3 setTitle:@"Aerial 3"];
    [aerial3 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #3"];
    [aerial3 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 55.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -45.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [aerial4 setTitle:@"Aerial 4"];
    [aerial4 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #4"];
    [aerial4 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 65.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -55.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *aerial5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [aerial5 setTitle:@"Aerial 5"];
    [aerial5 setSubtitle:@"This is Aerial #5"];
    [aerial5 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots];

    [mapView addAnnotation:aerial5];


     // *****************STREETS*****************************

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 27.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -37.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street1 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [street1 setTitle:@"Street 1"];
    [street1 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #1"];
    [street1 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street1];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 37.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -47.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street2 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [street2 setTitle:@"Street 2"];
    [street2 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #2"];
    [street2 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street2];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 57.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -67.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street3 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [street3 setTitle:@"Street 3"];
    [street3 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #3"];
    [street3 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street3];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 77.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -87.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street4 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [street4 setTitle:@"Street 4"];
    [street4 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #4"];
    [street4 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street4];

    workingCoordinate.latitude = 87.763856;
    workingCoordinate.longitude = -97.973034;
    iCodeBlogAnnotation *street5 = [[iCodeBlogAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    [street5 setTitle:@"Street 5"];
    [street5 setSubtitle:@"This is Street #5"];
    [street5 setAnnotationType:iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets];

    [mapView addAnnotation:street5];
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];


    }

    // here we are creating an array object BUT it is empty (it has no object in it)
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeHotels)
            {
                 // here is the line where we actually add objects to the array
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }


        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {

        cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

        }
        else
        {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }


    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {


        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeAerialShots)
            {
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {

            cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }



    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {


        for(iCodeBlogAnnotation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
        {
            if([annotation annotationType] == iCodeBlogAnnotationTypeStreets)
            {
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }

        if ([annotations count] > indexPath.row)
        {

            cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];

        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Empty";
        }


    }

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create the array outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath, with sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: or one of the other NSArray sorting methods.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor descriptorWithKey:@"aKey" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[mapView annotations] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sorter]];
```

Use whatever key you need in place of @"aKey" to get the sorting you want, and then use sortedArray, in the usual manner to populate the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `MapView` for each section:
hotelsMap, aerialsMap, streetsMap (or an array of size #sections holding `MapView` for each section)

add your annotations to the appropriate location/section.

for the array implementation `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //_maps is a mutable array of MapView's
    MapView* map = (indexPath.section < [_maps count] ? _maps[indexPath.section] : nil);
    NSString* text = (map && indexPath.row < [[map annotations] count] ? [[[map annotations]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title] : @"Empty");
    cell.textLabel.text = text;


    return cell;
}
```